# wmic terminate process not found

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

```
wmic process where name="abc.exe" call terminate
```

Sometimes I got the below error:

```
Description = Not Found
```

I suspect that this is because `abc.exe` is not running. Is this the case? If yes, is there a way to check if `abc.exe` is running before calling `terminate`?

Comment: When `abc.exe` is not running the message is `No Instance(s) Available.`. The message `Description = Not found` appears strange to me, I would rather expect `Name = Not found`…

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch example for killing any instances of Google Chrome using CommandLine with WMIC.

```bat
@echo off
Title BATCH Killing Program using CommandLine with WMIC
Set MyProgramPath=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
@for %%a in ("%MyProgramPath%") do set "MyProgramName=%%~nxa"
Set MyProgramPath=%MyProgramPath:\=\\%
set idx=0
:MAIN
cls
echo( Looking for any instances of "%MyProgramName%" ...
Set "Found="
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "CommandLine Like '%%%MyProgramPath%%%' And Name Like '%%%MyProgramName%%%'" get ProcessID /Value') do ( 
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        Set /a idx+=1
        set "MyPID[!idx!]=%%~nb"
        set "Found=True"
    )
)

If /I [!Found!] EQU [True] (
    echo( We found PID for "%MyProgramName%"
    @for /l %%i in (1,1,!idx!) do echo( %%i - !MyPID[%%i]!
    echo( Did you want to Kill this program "%MyProgramName%" [Y=YES]
    Set /P "Answer="
    IF /I [!Answer!] EQU [Y] (
        @for /l %%i in (1,1,!idx!) do Taskkill /T /F /PID !MyPID[%%i]!
    ) else (
        Endlocal
        Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
        Goto Main
    )
) else (
    Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak>nul
    Goto Main
)
```

Comment: It seems that it only uses `wmic` to find the process. And it still uses `taskkill` to actually kill it.

Comment: @Antediluvian What it is your end goal, can you describe it more and be more explicit ! What is the absolute path to your real program in your code ??

Comment: There is no path to the exe which is w3wp in my scenario. Basically I need to kill it if IIS has started a worker process. If not, it should not do anything.